# call to a member function connection() on null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im testing out something in laravel but the code below gives me error and I couldnt figure out whats the problem

Code :

```
    <?php
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$posts = \App\Models\Post::take(5)->get()->toArray();
file_put_contents('1.txt', print_r($posts, 1));
>
```

error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:3351 Stack trace: #0 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3317): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL) #1 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1861): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection() #2 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1834): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() #3 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1804): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() #4 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3561): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery() #5 /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/sr in /home/vowave/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3351
```

Comment: why are you manually requiring autoload and app if you're using laravel? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use php exec instead of http requests in one of my cron jobs

Comment: laravel supports [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling), check it out and see if that helps you.

Comment: That wont help me with what I want to do, if you can just tell me how I can fix it this way it would be awesome

Answer (score 4):

When you manually start laravel, you should call `bootstrap` method , like this:

```
 <?php
 $app = require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
 $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
 var_dump(Task::all());
```